# Trigger change event on select repopulation

Tags: jquery

I have an input which on change populates option entries in select. When the very first option is selected and then select is repopulated and first option is selected again (automatically) I want a change event to be triggered (because, an option with different value is selected).

What would be an elegent way to solve this with jQuery?

```
<select id="s">
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="r" value="remove">
<input type="button" id="a" value="add">

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var s = $("#s");
    var i = 100;

    s.change(function () {
        alert("changed");
    });

    $("#r").click(function () {
        s.find("option").remove();
    });

    $("#a").click(function () {
        s.append($("<option>", {
            value: ++i
        }).text(i));
        });


    // Select has changed from 1 to 101, 
    // so I want an event to be triggered
    $("#r").click();
    $("#a").click();

    // but I do not want it to be triggered 
    // when same value is selected
    $("#r").click();
    s.append($("<option>", { value: i }).text(i));
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs72d0ju/) created

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most subtle solution, adding `if(s.children().length===1)s.change();` to the add button functionality will work: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs72d0ju/1/)

```
$("#a").click(function () {        
    s.append($("<option>", {
        value: ++i
    }).text(i));
    if(s.children().length===1)s.change();
});
```

This simply checks if after adding, only one option exists and therefore the index is changed. Another solution is to compare the value (or selectedIndex) before and after adding, as done in the remove example below

---

As a sidenote, right now the delete button deletes all options, is that the intended behaviour? An example of deleting only one option (and triggering change if the select changed:

```
$("#r").click(function () {
    var sel = s.val();        
    s.children("option:last").remove(); //remove last option (use option:first to remove the first)
    var newval = s.val();
    if(sel !== newval && newval)s.change(); //fire change if the removed item was the selected one, but not if not items are left.
});
```

example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs72d0ju/2/)

As a 2nd sidenote, the add and remove could be combined into a single function (with a parameter stating add or remove), that checks the value before and after.